# r - use kable to group columns with sub columns having the same name

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, kable, kableextra

I am trying to use `kable` and `kableextra` to create a table that has different grouped headers but the same column names in the sub-headers

For example, if you look at the section "Grouped Columns/Headers" (page 14) of [Create Awesome LaTeX Table with knitr::kable andkableExtra](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) it is grouped but the sub-header names are different:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]

kable(dt, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
kable_styling() %>%
add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2" = 2, "Group 3" = 2))
```

What I am trying to do is something like this with the cars as groups (only using two cars for example):

```
Mazda RX4 | Datsun 710
----------------------
mpg | cyl | mpg | cyl
----------------------
21.0|   6 | 21.4|   6
```

or as another example:

```
Group 1 | Group 2
------------------
x  |  y | x  |  y
------------------
a  |  1 | b  |  2
c  |  3 | d  |  4
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with `knitr::kable`, but you might try [`gt`](https://github.com/rstudio/gt).

Comment: or [kableExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. Hope this helps:

**EDIT:** Changed the answer to make a HTML table but the logic remains!!

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)

df <- tibble('mpg_Mazda_RX4' = 21,
             'cyl_Mazda_RX4' = 6,
             'mpg_Datsun_710' = 21.4,
             'cyl_Datsun_710' = 6)
kable(df,
      "html",
      booktabs = T,
      align = c("r"),
      col.names = c("mpg","cyl","mpg","cyl")) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F,
                position = "left", font_size = 12) %>%
  add_header_above(c("Mazda RX4" = 2, "Datsun 710" = 2))
```

You have to pass column names directly to kable (doesn't change the dataframe column names).

Result:

[image: Result:]

Comment: hi @LuisSilva, i am trying to output to html. I think i follow your logic but the code you provided is not producing a table.

Comment: hi. The code you provided in your question was for a latex table thus i thought you wanted to make a PDF. Fixed the answer for HTML. Please try it now!

Comment: @LuisSilva thanks! This saved me a ton of work! Exactly what I was trying to figure out.